# Refresh JFrame contents DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, jframe, refresh, defaulttablemodel

I'm trying to figure out how to make a table window update once the model has changed using an example from another site.  Everything works but I can't figure how to refresh the window once the table model has changed.

EDIT: I used the suggestion from Bell and re-arranged some things so that the constructor calls my getmodel3 method to populate the table.  I thought I could use the setmodel method to change the model and update the table but it isn't working as I thought.  Here's what I thought would, but doesn't happen:

1. The `main` method creates a new instance of the table using the model passed from the `getmodel3` method.
2. After the table is constructed I call the `setmodel` method to load different data into a new model using the returned model from `getmodel4`.
3. The instance from step 1 is updated with new model data and the new data is shown in the table.

What actually happens is, a new instance is created and uses the model returned from `getmodel3`, then the `setmodel` method runs and updates the model variable from a different set of data, but the table doesn't show the change.

```
    public class myTable extends JFrame
    {

    public volatile DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) myTable.getmodel3();

    public void setmodel(DefaultTableModel newModel) 
    {
        this.model = newModel;
    }

    public myTable()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable( model );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        myTable frame = new myTable();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setmodel(getmodel4());
    }
```

Here is `getmodel3` which is identical to `getmodel4` except they point to different database files for different data.

```
    public static DefaultTableModel getmodel3(){
    Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<Object>();
    Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();

    try
    {
        //  Connect to an Access Database

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:c:\\sqlite3\\test.db";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        //  Read data from a table

        String sql = "Select * from Tasks";
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();

        //  Get column names

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
        {
            columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
        }

        //  Get row data

        while (rs.next())
        {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
            }

            data.addElement( row );
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println( e );
    }

    //  Create table with database data

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
    {
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };
System.out.println("got model");

return model;
```

}

Comment: This tech is dead.

Comment: Either create new `TableModel` and apply to the existing `JTable` or update the data within model itself

Comment: I'm able to update the data within the model but the table isn't showing the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with some of your help I finally figured it out.  `setModel` wasn't working because 1, it wasn't accessible from the scope of the method where I tried to use it, and 2 I tried to make my own setter `setmodel` but I had no idea what I was doing :).

In the end, I initialized in an easier to reach place so I didn't mess with objects in other methods.  Here is the working result that loads a table when main is called and later I can call the update method to reload it.  Thanks for the help folks.

```
public class able extends JFrame
{

//initialize here for easy access.  getmodel3() is the model getter method and 
//returns the defaultTableModel object

private static able frame =  new able();
private static JTable table = new JTable( getmodel3() );

//Start all main stuff here using the previously initialized objects.

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
    frame.getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}   

public static void update()
{
   table.setModel(getmodel3());
}

//This method makes the table model from sql result set and returns it.    
//(found online somewhere thanks to whoever wrote it)

public static DefaultTableModel getmodel3(){
    Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<Object>();
    Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();

    try
    {
        //  Connect to an Access Database

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:c:\\sqlite3\\test.db";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        //  Read data from a table

        String sql = "Select * from Tasks";
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();

        //  Get column names

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
        {
            columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
        }

        //  Get row data

        while (rs.next())
        {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
            }

            data.addElement( row );
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println( e );
    }

    //  Create table with database data

    DefaultTableModel model3 = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
    {
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };
System.out.println("got model");

return model3;
 }

public static DefaultTableModel getmodel4(){
    Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<Object>();
    Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();

    try
    {
        //  Connect to an Access Database

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:c:\\sqlite3\\test2.db";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        //  Read data from a table

        String sql = "Select * from Tasks";
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();

        //  Get column names

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
        {
            columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
        }

        //  Get row data

        while (rs.next())
        {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
            }

            data.addElement( row );
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println( e );
    }

    //  Create table with database data

    DefaultTableModel model3 = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
    {
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };
System.out.println("got model");

return model3;
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing model by using `table.getModel()` and set new/existing model using `table.setModel(yourModel)`

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
// do modification here
table.setModel(model);
```

Comment: Thanks, getModel is working but setModel isn't refreshing the window.  Any ideas?